# Changing color of font in mermaid js for a single message

Tags: reactjs, sequence-diagram

I'm using the mermaid plugin in my react project. I was wondering if there's a way to change the font color of a particular message when I render a sequence diagram.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty late to this question, but in case it is useful for anyone else that lands here... There are a couple of ways to style diagrams in Mermaid, which [the Mermaid docs](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=styling-and-classes) explain quite well.

The first is to directly style the Mermaid code:

```
flowchart LR
    id1(Start)-->id2(Stop)
    style id1 fill:#f9f,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px
    style id2 fill:#bbf,stroke:#f66,stroke-width:2px,color:#fff,stroke-dasharray: 5 5
```

Or apply classes within Mermaid so you can re-use stylings for different nodes:

```
flowchart LR
    A:::someclass --> B
    classDef someclass fill:#f96;
```

You can also assign classes to multiple nodes at the same time to make this a little cleaner for large diagrams (in this example, `className` is whatever you want to call your new class - i.e., `pinkNode`):

```
classDef className fill:#f9f,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;
class nodeId1,nodeId2 className;
```

Alternatively, you can create CSS styles and apply them to mermaid nodes:

```
<style>
    .cssClass > rect{
        fill:#FF0000;
        stroke:#FFFF00;
        stroke-width:4px;
    }
</style>
```

And this would be your corresponding mermaid code:

```
flowchart LR;
    A-->B[AAA<span>BBB</span>]
    B-->D
    class A cssClass
```

Comment: None of the cited examples from the documentation address the question about font color

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately that stuff doesn't work on sequence diagrams.
It IS possible, but a bit hack-y.
This DOES work in https://mermaid.live
Just copy and paste this code into mermaid live to see it.

```
sequenceDiagram
Fred->>Jill:Hello my Snookums
note over Fred:True Love
Jill->>Fred:Oh my Darling!
note over Jill:True Love Returned

%%{init:{'theme':'forest'}}%%
%%{init:{'themeCSS':'.messageLine0:nth-of-type(2) { stroke: #f00; };.messageText:nth-of-type(1) { fill: green; font-size: 30px !important;}; g:nth-of-type(3) rect.actor { stroke:#00f;fill: #ff0; }; g:nth-of-type(5) .note { stroke:#00f;fill: #ff0; };#arrowhead path {stroke: blue; fill:#f00;};'}}%%
```

The secret is the themeCSS, and the nth-of-type to select particular lines
The next line is also really ugly because they all have to fit within the JSON single value.
This is just CSS, but it was a little fiddly getting the particular classes and elements and stuff.

```
.messageLine0:nth-of-type(2) { stroke: #f00; };
.messageText:nth-of-type(1) { fill: green; font-size: 30px !important;}
g:nth-of-type(3) rect.actor { stroke:#00f;fill: #ff0; };
g:nth-of-type(5) .note { stroke:#00f;fill: #ff0; };
#arrowhead path {stroke: blue; fill:#f00;};
```

The messages are relatively easy to select the particular line
The notes (.note) and the participants (rect.actor) take a little working with the nth of type numbers.
The arrowheads all have to be the same color
If you edit the code after, you may have to re-align all the colors again